# python-shell send json from nodejs to python

Tags: python, node.js

At the nodejs side I created a script for sending json to python, but I don't know how to retrieve these data and convert it into dictionary, Anyone can help me on this issue?

```
  const schedule = require('node-schedule');
  const PythonShell = require('python-shell');
  let d = new Date('2018-04-16 10:16:10')
  var pyshell = new PythonShell('../a.py', { mode: 'json' });
  let j = schedule.scheduleJob(d, () => {
    pyshell.send({test:1,ff:2});
    pyshell.end(err => {
        if (err) res.send("Error : ", err);
    });
    pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
        // console.log(message)
        // handle message (a line of text from stdout, parsed as JSON)
    });
});
```

**a.py**

```
import sys, json
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
f = json.loads(lines[0])
print(f)
```

It gives me an error

> `undefined:1`
>
> `{'test': 1, 'ff': 2}`
>
> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?!

Comment: you can use childprocess spwan to run your python script

Comment: see my edits above

Comment: hmm, using the `stringify` you could just change the `python-shell` mode for `'text'`. Is there a reason you switched to `child_process`?

Comment: same problem here, how does python receive the data, is it in json format directly when you use mode json or do you have to call json.loads, also how to read it

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of pythonshell is stated that each "message" in the dataflow should end on "\n". Otherwise pythonshell cannot interpret it as valide message. Here you can read more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

> **options**: the execution options, consisting of:
>   mode: Configures how data is exchanged when data flows through stdin and stdout. The possible values are:
>
> 1. **text**: each line of data (ending with "\n") is emitted as a message (default)
> 2. **json**: each line of data ***(ending with "\n")*** is parsed as JSON and emitted as a message
> 3. **binary**: data is streamed as-is through stdout and stdin